# When user clicks on the add to cart, the items should get stored inside the table

Tags: jsp

```
<table>
<input type = "text" name ="color" id="color"> 
<input type = "text" name ="paint" id="paint">
<input type = "text" name ="build" id="build">
<input type = "text" name ="combine" id="combine">
<input type = "button" onclick="addto()"value="add to cart"/>`
```

these are the text field disbled in the webpage. When user types the value and click in the add to cart button the value of this should store in the table space provided below.

```
<table>  
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text"> 
<input type="text">`
```

This is the code for table when user fills the details and click on the display button the value should store in this table values.

Comment: can you show your code for `addto()` ?

Comment: actually i need a code to that function only i did not written any code yet to that addto().

Comment: do you need to save data in db or just show that in another table ? what you need to achieve?

Comment: i just want to store that in the another table .were user can cross verify  whether the entered value are right or not that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You firstly need to get all data from input box in jquery/js using `.val()` and then use `.append(..)` to add the data inside your table as a new row .So your jquery  code will look like below :

```
function addto() {
    //getting value from input box
      var color = $("#color").val();
      var paint = $("#paint").val();
      var build = $("#build").val();
      var combine = $("#combine").val();
      var appends = '<tr><td><input type="text" value=' + color + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + paint + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + build + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + combine + '></td></tr>'
    //appending new row inside table
      $("#abc").append(appends);
    }
```

**Demo Code** :

```js
function addto() {
  //getting value from input box
  var color = $("#color").val();
  var paint = $("#paint").val();
  var build = $("#build").val();
  var combine = $("#combine").val();
  var appends = '<tr><td><input type="text" value=' + color + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + paint + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + build + '></td><td><input type="text" value=' + combine + '></td><td><button type="button" onclick="remove(this)" >Remove</button></td></tr>'
  //appending new row inside table
  $("#abc").append(appends);
}

function remove(ele){
//Removing <tr> 
ele.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```css
button{
color:black;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Color : <input type="text" name="color" id="color"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paint : <input type="text" name="paint" id="paint"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Build : <input type="text" name="build" id="build"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Combine : <input type="text" name="combine" id="combine"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addto()" value="Add to cart" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Your Typed Data Will Display Here :



<table id="abc" border="1">
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Paint</th>
      <th>Build</th>
      <th>Combine</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: glad i helped :) don't forget to set this answer as accepted

Comment: In future if i need to add this row of table cart in to data base what changes should i make please help me for this

Comment: that depend on what you use , if you use ajax then onclick event you can you get all value from input and then insert the value in db or form is other option.

Comment: In   var color =$("#color").val(); #color  is value of id right???

Comment: yes that is `id` of input .. you need to use `#` with id name to get value  of a particular input .